# Change broker configuration for kafka cluster on confluent cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-cloud

I'm using kafka for a project and specifically I'm using Confluent Cloud's managed kafka. I need to update my broker configuration (specifically the field offsets.retention.minutes), but I'm at a bit of a loss at **how** I'm supposed to do this. Their online console provides no way to do so that I can see, I've tried using their proprietary 'confluent' CLI which **claims** to be able to accomplish what I want (via: https://docs.confluent.io/confluent-cli/current/command-reference/kafka/broker/confluent_kafka_broker_update.html#confluent-kafka-broker-update), but I have to pass a URL to that tool to execute that particular command (other commands work fine, but not the broker ones) and the tool fails when I pass it the default REST URL provided in the confluent cloud UI.

For completeness though, the commands I've tried to run are in the following forms:

```
confluent kafka broker update --all --url https://<CLUSTER_ID>.us-west1.gcp.confluent.cloud:443 --config offsets.retention.minutes=262800
```

which yields: "Error: unable to establish Kafka REST connection: https://<CLUSTER_ID>.us-west1.gcp.confluent.cloud:44/v3: dial tcp 35.247.31.53:44: i/o timeout" (it appears to be doing something **DEEPLY** weird with the port number as it has DROPPED the 3.....

```
confluent kafka broker update --all --url https://<CLUSTER_ID>.us-west1.gcp.confluent.cloud --config offsets.retention.minutes=262800
```

which yields: "Error: REST request failed: Not Found (0)"

```
confluent kafka broker update --all --url https://<CLUSTER_ID>.us-west1.gcp.confluent.cloud:443/kafka --config offsets.retention.minutes=262800
```

which yields: "Error: REST request failed: HTTP 404 Not Found (404)" (at least it's a more normal error).

I see references online about logging into the brokers and manually changing the server.properties file to include my configuration and manually restarting the server, which I'm totally fine with, but I cannot see any concrete machine that I should be able to login to to accomplish this.

So, how can I set a broker configuration value in Confluent Cloud's managed kafka offering? I am a paid customer btw, if that matters for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question is apparently, that I cannot change this setting on the confluent cloud. It *is* possible to change cluster settings if you pay for a dedicated cluster, but if you do that then there is only a tiny subset of broker configuration fields that can be changed, and 'offsets.retention.minutes' is not one of them.

From: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#compaction

> You cannot edit cluster settings on Confluent Cloud on Basic or Standard clusters, but you can edit certain topic configurations after a topic has been created. For a list of editable topic settings, see Custom topic settings for all cluster types.

> You can change some configuration settings on Dedicated clusters using the Kafka CLI or REST API. See Change cluster settings for Dedicated clusters.

Kudos to a very helpful confluent support rep that answered a piece of documentation feedback with some helpful links that led me to this information.